# if overridden method's return type is primitive (e.g. double) ,can we change return type of overriding method (e.g. int ,char)?

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding

As shown below :

Method to be overriden:

```
double add (int a ,int b){  

}
```

Method overridding above method:

```
int add(int a,int b){

}
```

Comment: Why you can't just try it?

Comment: Looks like you are missing some code. Can you please update this?

Comment: No, to do so would mean that anyone using the superclass interface would receive an invalid value if invoking the subclass's method.

Comment: This is sort of a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773840/override-method-with-different-signature

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With primitive types it is not possible, but there is a feature added to JDK 1.5 called [covariant return types](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/covariant_return_types_in_java). So, using this  feature, a subclass could return a more specific type than the one declared on the parent class.

The following code compiles fine in JDK 1.7

```
public static class A {
   Number go() { return 0; };
}

public static class B extends A {
  @Override
  Integer go() { return 0; }
}
```

See [JLS Example 8.4.8.3-1. Covariant Return Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#d5e11368)

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot change the return type. You can overload a method by providing alternate or additional input.

i.e.

```
int add(int a, int b, int c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to make the base type a parameterized type, and assert the return type when you extend or instantiate it.